# How to target specific columns with rowCallback jquery for DT::Datatable in R

Tags: jquery, r, dt

I'm trying to modify my current rowcallback code to make it target for instance column 1 and 4:last column.

the current line I have targets col 3:end

```
 "for (i =  3; i < data.length; i++) {",
```

I've tried to write it like this:

```
 "for (i = 1 | i =  3; i < data.length; i++) {",
```

but then it stops working. Struggling to find the right syntax

What I have right now is this:

```
library(DT)
  Table_opts <- list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    searching = F,
    pageLength = 50,
    searchHighlight = TRUE,
    colReorder = TRUE,
    fixedHeader = TRUE,
    buttons = c('csv', 'print'),
    paging    = TRUE,
    deferRender = TRUE,
    scrollX = T,
    scrollY = 310,
    rowCallback = JS(
      "function(row, data) {",
      "for (i =  3; i < data.length; i++) {",
      "if (data[i]>1 | data[i]<0){",
      "$('td:eq('+i+')', row).html(data[i].toExponential(1));",
      "}",
      "}",
      "}")
  )
DT::datatable(mtcars, rownames = F, selection = "single",
              extensions = c('Buttons', 'FixedHeader',  'ColReorder','Scroller'), options = Table_opts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip `i=2`, you can do:

```
for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (i == 2) {
    continue;
  }
  ......
}
```

Comment: what would be the syntax if you want to target just column 2 and 3 specifically?

Comment: @Mark `var columns = [2,3]; for(var i=0; i < columns.length; ++i){ something with data[columns[i]];}`